# Powershell AD user group member

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there any simple way to just filter user group member like this:

```
$abcgroup = (Get-ADUser -Identity username –Properties MemberOf) | where {$_.MemberOf -like "*ABC*"}| Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | FT MemberOf -AutoSize
```

And return user group just the ABC-XYZ instead of every single group as output, otherwise any easy method to process all the group name and just extract the any group name start with ABC-*

Thanks

Comment: If you're looking for members of groups, you could try `Get-ADGroupMember` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make it a little bit simpler, both in server and local processing:

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(&(member=$((Get-ADUser username).distinguishedName))(sAMAccountName=abc-*))"
```

This would get all the groups that include selected user and their name matches the pattern. This would only include two LDAP requests (one for getting user DN, one for getting all the groups). All the selection will be done on the server and only interesting values will be returned, meaning less data transfer and less post-processing (i.e. filtering) on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this might work:

```
$abcgroup = (Get-ADUser -Identity username –Properties MemberOf).MemberOf | 
             Where-Object {$_ -match '^cn=ABC-'} | ForEach-Object {(Get-ADGroup -Identity $_).Name}

$abcgroup | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thanks, I test at my home lab seems working perfectly, will test it when I back office :) Thanks a lot